# Is it required to broadcast the addresses generated locally to the bitcoin network?

Tags: blockchain, client, address-generation

Like the transactions  are broadcasted to the bitcoin network , is it required that locally generated addresses also need to be boradcasted to the bitcoin network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can generate trillions of addresses (private keys) and the rest of the network don't need to know about them until you make transactions to each of them.

Comment: Is this means that Suppose i have generated the address  locally and now i want my friend to send me coins then is that means he can send me directly  ? or my locally generated address will be firstly added on blockchain ?

Comment: @PankajKumar You should send your address to your friend, e.g. via message/SMS

Comment: yes that need to be send to my friend firstly only then my friend able to know that whats my address, thanks i found the answer